# core dump at libc-2.20.so

Tags: qt, gcc, lib

I get a core dump when running my qt5 application "LinuxClient" on embedded device.
I use "gdb -c core.LinuxClient.24849.6.1509522596" to get the stack below:

```
Core was generated by `./LinuxClient'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    #0  0x742e4d84 in ?? ()
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x742e4d84 in ?? ()   0x742e4d84 - 0x742b9000  =  0x2BD84
    #1  0x742e8884 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

    (gdb) i proc m
    Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
    0x8000   0x25e000   0x256000        0x0 /usr/share/qt5/app/mhclient/LinuxClient
    0x266000   0x26b000     0x5000   0x256000 /usr/share/qt5/app/mhclient/LinuxClient
    0x6fa16000 0x6fa19000     0x3000        0x0 /usr/lib/libxcb-util.so.1.0.0
    0x6fa19000 0x6fa20000     0x7000     0x3000 /usr/lib/libxcb-util.so.1.0.0
    ...
    ...
    0x74144000 0x74147000     0x3000    0x4b000 /usr/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.3.2
    0x74148000 0x7418b000    0x43000        0x0 /usr/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.3.2
    0x7418b000 0x74192000     0x7000    0x43000 /usr/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.3.2
    0x74192000 0x74194000     0x2000    0x42000 /usr/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.3.2
    0x74194000 0x742ad000   0x119000        0x0 /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.3.2
    0x742ad000 0x742b4000     0x7000   0x119000 /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.3.2
    0x742b4000 0x742b9000     0x5000   0x118000 /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.3.2
    0x742b9000 0x743de000   0x125000        0x0 /lib/libc-2.20.so
    0x743de000 0x743e6000     0x8000   0x125000 /lib/libc-2.20.so
    0x743e6000 0x743e8000     0x2000   0x125000 /lib/libc-2.20.so
    0x743e8000 0x743e9000     0x1000   0x127000 /lib/libc-2.20.so
    0x743ec000 0x74408000    0x1c000        0x0 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x74408000 0x7440f000     0x7000    0x1c000 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x7440f000 0x74410000     0x1000    0x1b000 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-readelf -r LinuxClient ( just show the item for grep libc )
    Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x12aa4 contains 50 entries:
    Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
    00269338  0002c316 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   0001bf70   __libc_start_main

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-readelf -a /lib/libc-2.20.so ( just show the item code nearby __libc_start_main )
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 2207 entries:                                          
Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name    
2081: 000c5f30    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 tcgetpgrp@@GLIBC_2.4         
2082: 000163a8   620 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.4 
2083: 0002cf90     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 __default_rt_sa_restorer@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

Many other times I used bt to find dumped at __default_rt_sa_restorer, what does it mean?
Does it mean the dump was cuased by libc rather than my code? Or Error comes from the cross compiling of libc?

Answer (score 0):

This suggest that you do not have binaries and debugging information installed which match the coredump:

```
Core was generated by `./LinuxClient'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    #0  0x742e4d84 in ?? ()
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x742e4d84 in ?? ()   0x742e4d84 - 0x742b9000  =  0x2BD84
    #1  0x742e8884 in ?? ()
```

You need to generate the backtrace in exactly the environment which produced the coredump (usually by installing the exact same distribution package versions).

Comment: Yes, you are right and it's another issue. My libs are generated by yocto, currently I do not have the method to build the libs with debugging information.